# C++ Expose Already Existing Instance of Objects to a Scripting Language

Tags: c++, python, scripting, lua

So, I want to be able to modify already instanced C++ objects in a scripting language. I have been looking at Lua with LuaBind and Python with SWIG or Boost::Python, but all I see is how to make new instances of the objects, but I want to modify already existing ones.
Example:

C++:

```
Player playerOne = new Player();
```

Scripting Language :

```
playerOne.Transform.x += 5;
```

Is this possible, and if so, wat would you suggest as a good  Language/library to achieve this with?

Answer (score 1):

In my main project we use LuaBind, and it works pretty well. We do basically what you're asking to do. We have existing C++ objects where we want behavior extended in various ways, but it would be a lot of work and risky to do those changes in behavior in the C++ code for the object itself.

So in your example, you'd want at least 2 C++ wrapper classes - one that represents the 'Game' that allows you to write an API function to return players, and a wrapper class that wraps the  C++ player class that you can return to lua. Each wrapper function would have api functions/properties that would fiddle with the individual object it's wrapped internally that lua could call and pass values to. Here is a link to an article giving you pretty straightforward examples of using LuaBind and what it looks like:

http://blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/cxx/luabind-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

I recently needed to do the same thing. I also considered (and used) Boost.Python but personally (as much as I love Boost) I felt it was a little overkill to drag in half the Boost library to get one feature.

So, if you're interested, I recently implemented a very light-weight Python wrapper library called ECS:Python. ECS:Python (Embedded C++ Scripting with Python) is designed specifically for C++ developers that wish to expose objects FROM a C++ application TO an embedded Python interpreter for interactive scripting.

Its free (BSD) and open source: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ecspython

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism that can *magic* values into a scripting language from the host language. If you want a particular object instances to be accessible in the scripting language, it must be *given* to the scripting language via some function.

This is no different from any other properly encapsulated C++ type. If object A creates and stores some instance T, then the only way object B can get it is if it calls a function on A that returns T.

Comment: I assume I could do something like call a function like getPlayers(); or something that returns a list of pointers to players or something then correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the problems in my project. Have a look at my post in the Ogre3d forums:
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=41631&p=332200&hilit=mrmclovin#p405204

Code example:

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
  try
  {
    // Initialize the python interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Create a module dynamically
    object module((handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("NameOfMyModule")))));

    // Retrieve the module's namespace
    object main_namespace(module.attr("__dict__"));

    // Put a c++ class named "Car" exported using boost.python into our module
    main_namespace["Car"] = class_<Car>("Car")
                                               .def("drive", &Car::drive)......;

   // The class car now exists in a dynamic module
   // and that module is accessable everywhere as longs as the python interpreter exists

   // Create a instance of Car here
   Car* myCar = new Car(...);

   // Now simply add it to the module. Make sure you have exposed class Car before adding instances
   main_namespace["car_instance"] = object(ptr(myCar)); // the boost python ptr() class make sure not to copy the pointee but only copy pointer adress
  }
  catch( error_already_set )
  {
    PyErr_Print();
  }

  return 0;
}
```